# How to run/set up the "stlink" helper program for assembly programming from a zip file at github for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, github, assembly, arm, cortex-m

I am new both at Ubuntu (20.04) and assembly programming. What I need to do is to set up the "stlink" stlink-1.6.1-1.x86_64.rpm file  and/or  Source code.zip file in this github  link for release version v1.6.1 ( zip files are at the bottom of the explanations):

https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink/releases/tag/v1.6.1.

(Stlink is a helper program to communicate between the computer and the Arm Cortex m4 STM32F407 Discovery Board.)

I have double click the zip files and it does not started any kind of set up, it just go into the main folder in the zip file. Can anyone help me setting up this program?

Comment: have you tried openocd?  what exactly do you want to do there are many programs that can communicate with that hardware.

Comment: @esra if you are on Ubuntu, download the `.deb` file and run in a new terminal, under the download directory : `sudo dpkg -i your-file.deb`

Comment: @BertrandMartel thanks for the useful comment, the problem is solved with your sugesstion  .deb file.

Comment: @old_timer Iwould like to write an assembly code some of some mathematical operations. what is openocd I 've never heard of it?

Comment: Just look it up.  It speaks jtag and swd, in particular for arm cores.  free, open source.  stlink is not your only way into the part.